# Does "git gc" also run "git repack"?

Tags: git, garbage-collection

I have turned off git's annoying automatic repacking functionality (I guess that most git-users know the "repacking for optimal performance" message when working with git) and am instead invoking "git gc" overnight with a cronjob.

However I am unsure if that is enough and whether I should also run "git repack" before or after "git gc".

The manpages of "git repack" and "git gc" don't mention any connection between the two, and the manpage of "git repack" actually contains this phrase:

> Instead, the loose unreachable objects will be pruned according to
>   normal expiry rules with the next git gc invocation.

This would indicate to me that "git gc" is not sufficient for all house-keeping tasks and "git repack" is also needed. Is that correct and what housekeeping-commands should be used for git?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git repack` just repacks the objects.

`git gc` repacks them and throws away the old unreachable objects.

To verify you can do something like `find .git/objects` before and after `git gc`: before you should see all new objects as separate files. Afterwards there should be only one big pack file.

For details you can also have a look at the code: In builtin/gc.c the repack command is [prepared](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/gc.c#L286) and [executed](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/gc.c#L346).

Comment: So, the answer of the question would then be: "no, git-gc is sufficient for housekeeping and git-repack need not be invoked seperately.", correct?

Comment: The answer would be "yes, `git gc` also runs `git repack`" ;) Therefore, yes, `git gc` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

2022 update (8 years later)

`git gc` will run `repack` indeed.
But not your usual repack. A new `git repack --cruft`, generating **cruft packs**.

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), a mechanism to pack unreachable objects into a "**cruft pack**", instead of ejecting them into loose form to be reclaimed later, has been introduced.

Activate said mechanism with:

```
git config --global gc.cruftPacks true
```

See [commit a613164](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a613164257b46700ca583bdcab160c712ad392fe), [commit 5b92477](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b92477f896f147d02bd2e9168a780940b57cfc5), [commit ddee370](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ddee3703b36e96056f11ddc4621707b6054bab48), [commit 72263ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72263ffc322d0b6c8646a4f096981a0b4bad17ba), [commit 4571324](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4571324b99fcf7bd9e58fce677801fbf72b0e0a5), [commit f9825d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9825d1cf752b8d04a3e9193ff6fdb54d09e28a3), [commit a7d4938](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7d493833fe615211fd329183e59cec08496fb90), [commit fb546d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb546d6e4395cedf46a81ce91213b61992b14ff5), [commit 2fb9040](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2fb90409b8133803bae89773ac9a9db629443dc6), [commit b757353](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b757353676d6ffe1ac275366fa8b5b42b5d9727d), [commit fa23090](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa23090b0c5cc27d0720535e27236fef9b409efb), [commit 2bd4427](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2bd44278244d3dc4cc11916ecb1f31f826709a20), [commit 5dfaf49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5dfaf49a5a651d3e8c3552bc2e833312a3671a4f), [commit d9fef9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9fef9d90d27b6794350ec3bc622042b79397088), [commit 1c573cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c573cdd7219db5600fb2b5249f7c8835c8d416d), [commit 94cd775](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94cd775a6c52a99caeb1278c3d8044ee109e2d3e), [commit 3d89a8c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d89a8c11801af1f7aae9d009240fd43cf322845) (20 May 2022) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a50036d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a50036da1a39806a8ae1aba2e2f2fea6f7fb8e08), 03 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`Documentation/technical`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d89a8c11801af1f7aae9d009240fd43cf322845): add cruft-packs.txt
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> Create a technical document to explain cruft packs.
> It contains a brief overview of the problem, some background, details on the implementation, and a couple of alternative approaches not considered here.

`technical/cruft-packs` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3d89a8c11801af1f7aae9d009240fd43cf322845/Documentation/technical/cruft-packs.txt#L1-L123):

> ## Cruft packs
>
> The cruft packs feature offer an alternative to Git's traditional mechanism of
> removing unreachable objects. This document provides an overview of Git's
> pruning mechanism, and how a cruft pack can be used instead to accomplish the
> same.
>
> ### Background
>
> To remove unreachable objects from your repository, Git offers `git repack -Ad`
> (see [`git repack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack)). Quoting from the documentation:
>
> > [quote]
> > [...] unreachable objects in a previous pack become loose, unpacked objects,
> > instead of being left in the old pack. [...] loose unreachable objects will be
> > pruned according to normal expiry rules with the next 'git gc' invocation.
>
> Unreachable objects aren't removed immediately, since doing so could race with
> an incoming push which may reference an object which is about to be deleted.
> Instead, those unreachable objects are stored as loose object and stay that way
> until they are older than the expiration window, at which point they are removed
> by [`git prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune).
>
> Git must store these unreachable objects loose in order to keep track of their
> per-object mtimes. If these unreachable objects were written into one big pack,
> then either freshening that pack (because an object contained within it was
> re-written) or creating a new pack of unreachable objects would cause the pack's
> mtime to get updated, and the objects within it would never leave the expiration
> window.
> Instead, objects are stored loose in order to keep track of the
> individual object mtimes and avoid a situation where all cruft objects are
> freshened at once.
>
> This can lead to undesirable situations when a repository contains many
> unreachable objects which have not yet left the grace period.
> Having large
> directories in the shards of `.git/objects` can lead to decreased performance in
> the repository.
> But given enough unreachable objects, this can lead to inode
> starvation and degrade the performance of the whole system.
> Since we
> can never pack those objects, these repositories often take up a large amount of
> disk space, since we can only zlib compress them, but not store them in delta
> chains.
>
> ### Cruft packs
>
> A cruft pack eliminates the need for storing unreachable objects in a loose
> state by including the per-object mtimes in a separate file alongside a single
> pack containing all loose objects.
>
> A cruft pack is written by `git repack --cruft` when generating a new pack.
> [`git pack-objects`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-objects)'s `--cruft` option. Note that `git repack --cruft`
> is a classic all-into-one repack, meaning that everything in the resulting pack is
> reachable, and everything else is unreachable.
> Once written, the `--cruft`
> option instructs `git repack` to generate another pack containing only objects
> not packed in the previous step (which equates to packing all unreachable
> objects together).
>
> This progresses as follows:
>
> 1. Enumerate every object, marking any object which is (a) not contained in a
>    kept-pack, and (b) whose mtime is within the grace period as a traversal
>    tip.
> 2. Perform a reachability traversal based on the tips gathered in the previous
>    step, adding every object along the way to the pack.
> 3. Write the pack out, along with a `.mtimes` file that records the per-object
>    timestamps.
>
> This mode is invoked internally by [`git repack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack) when instructed to
> write a cruft pack. Crucially, the set of in-core kept packs is exactly the set
> of packs which will not be deleted by the repack; in other words, they contain
> all of the repository's reachable objects.
>
> When a repository already has a cruft pack, `git repack --cruft` typically only
> adds objects to it.
> An exception to this is when `git repack` is given the
> `--cruft-expiration` option, which allows the generated cruft pack to omit
> expired objects instead of waiting for [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) to expire those objects
> later on.
>
> It is [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) that is typically responsible for removing expired
> unreachable objects.
>
> ### Caution for mixed-version environments
>
> Repositories that have cruft packs in them will continue to work with any older
> version of Git.
> Note, however, that previous versions of Git which do not
> understand the `.mtimes` file will use the cruft pack's mtime as the mtime for
> all of the objects in it. In other words, do not expect older (pre-cruft pack)
> versions of Git to interpret or even read the contents of the `.mtimes` file.
>
> Note that having mixed versions of Git GC-ing the same repository can lead to
> unreachable objects never being completely pruned.
> This can happen under the
> following circumstances:
>
> - An older version of Git running GC explodes the contents of an existing
>   cruft pack loose, using the cruft pack's mtime.
> - A newer version running GC collects those loose objects into a cruft pack,
>   where the `.mtime` file reflects the loose object's actual mtimes, but the
>   cruft pack mtime is "now".
>
> Repeating this process will lead to unreachable objects not getting pruned as a
> result of repeatedly resetting the objects' mtimes to the present time.
>
> If you are GC-ing repositories in a mixed version environment, consider omitting
> the `--cruft` option when using [`git repack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack) and [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc), and
> leaving the `gc.cruftPacks` configuration unset until all writers understand
> cruft packs.
>
> ### Alternatives
>
> Notable alternatives to this design include:
>
> - The location of the per-object mtime data, and
> - Storing unreachable objects in multiple cruft packs.
>
> On the location of mtime data, a new auxiliary file tied to the pack was chosen
> to avoid complicating the `.idx` format. If the `.idx` format were ever to gain
> support for optional chunks of data, it may make sense to consolidate the
> `.mtimes` format into the `.idx` itself.
>
> Storing unreachable objects among multiple cruft packs (e.g., creating a new
> cruft pack during each repacking operation including only unreachable objects
> which aren't already stored in an earlier cruft pack) is significantly more
> complicated to construct, and so aren't pursued here. The obvious drawback to
> the current implementation is that the entire cruft pack must be re-written from
> scratch.

And:

> ### [`builtin/gc.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b92477f896f147d02bd2e9168a780940b57cfc5): conditionally avoid pruning objects via loose
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> Expose the new [`git repack --cruft`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5b92477f896f147d02bd2e9168a780940b57cfc5/Documentation/git-repack.txt#L66)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack#Documentation/git-repack.txt---cruft))</sup> mode from [`git gc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5b92477f896f147d02bd2e9168a780940b57cfc5/Documentation/git-gc.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))</sup> via a new opt-in flag.
> When invoked like [`git gc --cruft`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5b92477f896f147d02bd2e9168a780940b57cfc5/Documentation/git-gc.txt#L57)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#Documentation/git-gc.txt---cruft))</sup>, `git gc` will avoid exploding unreachable objects as loose ones, and instead create a cruft pack and `.mtimes` file.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5b92477f896f147d02bd2e9168a780940b57cfc5/Documentation/config/gc.txt#L84-L88):

> ### `gc.cruftPacks`
>
> Store unreachable objects in a cruft pack (see
> [`git repack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack)) instead of as loose objects.
>
> The default
> is `false`.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5b92477f896f147d02bd2e9168a780940b57cfc5/Documentation/config/gc.txt#L90-L98):

> When '`git gc`' is run, it will call '`prune --expire 2.weeks.ago`'
> (and '`repack --cruft --cruft-expiration 2.weeks.ago`' if using
> cruft packs via `gc.cruftPacks` or `--cruft`).
>
> Override the
> grace period with this config variable.
>
> The value "now" may be
> used to disable this grace period and always prune unreachable
> objects immediately, or "never" may be used to suppress pruning.
> This feature helps prevent corruption when '`git gc`' runs
> concurrently with another process writing to the repository; see
> the "NOTES" section of [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc).

`git gc` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5b92477f896f147d02bd2e9168a780940b57cfc5/Documentation/git-gc.txt#L57-L61):

> ### `--cruft`
>
> When expiring unreachable objects, pack them separately into a
> cruft pack instead of storing the loose objects as loose
> objects.

---

With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), enable `gc.cruftpacks` by default for those who opt into `feature.experimental` setting.

See [commit c695592](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c695592850a3b4b7857fc11721cbc7d2b332f41e), [commit 12253ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12253ab6d0033aa8214c8a15bc2ea37ff052ff1c) (26 Oct 2022) by [Emily Shaffer (`nasamuffin`)](https://github.com/nasamuffin).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit bdd42e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdd42e34e3fdca79e20e30bcc03e99138e59c992), 08 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c695592850a3b4b7857fc11721cbc7d2b332f41e): let feature.experimental imply gc.cruftPacks=true
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Emily Shaffer</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> We are interested in exploring whether gc.cruftPacks=true should become the default value.
>
> To determine whether it is safe to do so, let's encourage more users to try it out.
>
> Users who have set `feature.experimental=true` have already volunteered to try new and possibly-breaking config changes, so let's try this new default with that set of users.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c695592850a3b4b7857fc11721cbc7d2b332f41e/Documentation/config/feature.txt#L17-L19):

> - `gc.cruftPacks=true` reduces disk space used by unreachable objects during
>   garbage collection, preventing loose object explosions.

[Example](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12253ab6d0033aa8214c8a15bc2ea37ff052ff1c):

```
git reset HEAD~2
git -c gc.cruftPacks=true gc
# or
git gc --cruft

find .git/objects/pack -name "*.mtimes" >mtimes
sed -e 's/\.mtimes$/\.pack/g' mtimes >packs 
while read pack
do
  test_path_is_file "$pack" || return 1
done <packs
```

There should be no pack file produced there, since the last two commits are no longer reachable.

---

With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), "[`git repack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ad9096881d451bdb56d713a4c7d271dda3662cb2/Documentation/git-repack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack))</sup> learns to send cruft objects out of the way into packfiles outside the repository.

See [commit 91badeb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/91badeba32d31d4dcc695a8888e5b697b4c3d90c), [commit c12cda4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c12cda479eb103bc364e299a2e5654a7165df3cd), [commit eddad36](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eddad3686080553bb1e6ffa6d9394912f9427823), [commit 4e7b65b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e7b65ba8e7b4174c4ab249b64c6cb3ad0009732) (24 Oct 2022) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Taylor Blau -- `ttaylorr` --](https://github.com/ttaylorr) in [commit ad90968](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad9096881d451bdb56d713a4c7d271dda3662cb2), 18 Nov 2022)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/repack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/91badeba32d31d4dcc695a8888e5b697b4c3d90c): implement `--expire-to` for storing pruned objects
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> When pruning objects with `--cruft`, [`git repack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/91badeba32d31d4dcc695a8888e5b697b4c3d90c/Documentation/git-repack.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack))</sup> offers some flexibility when selecting the set of which objects are pruned via the `--cruft-expiration` option.
>
> This is useful for expiring objects which are older than the grace period, making races where to-be-pruned objects become reachable and then ancestors of freshly pushed objects, leaving the repository in a corrupt state [after pruning substantially less likely](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20190319001829.GL29661@sigill.intra.peff.net/).
>
> But in practice, such races are impossible to avoid entirely, no matter how long the grace period is.
> To prevent this race, it is often advisable to temporarily put a repository into a read-only state.
> But in practice, this is not always practical, and so some middle ground would be nice.
>
> This patch introduces a new option, `--expire-to`, which teaches `git repack` to write an additional cruft pack containing just the objects which were pruned from the repository.
> The caller can specify a directory outside of the current repository as the destination for this second cruft pack.
>
> This makes it possible to prune objects from a repository, while still holding onto a supplemental copy of them outside of the original repository.
> Having this copy on-disk makes it substantially easier to recover objects when the aforementioned race is encountered.
>
> `--expire-to` is implemented in a somewhat convoluted manner, which is to take advantage of the fact that the first time `write_cruft_pack()` is called, it adds the name of the cruft pack to the `names` string list.
> That means the second time we call `write_cruft_pack()`, objects in the previously-written cruft pack will be excluded.
>
> As long as the caller ensures that no objects are expired during the second pass, this is sufficient to generate a cruft pack containing all objects which don't appear in any of the new packs written by `git repack`, including the cruft pack.
> In other words, all of the objects which are about to be pruned from the repository.
>
> It is important to note that the destination in `--expire-to` does not necessarily need to be a Git repository (though it can be) Notably, the expired packs do not contain all ancestors of expired objects.
> So if the source repository contains something like:
>
> ```
> <unreachable>
>              /
>     C1 --- C2
>       \
> ads/master
> ```
>
> where C2 is unreachable, but has a parent (C1) which is reachable, and C2 would be pruned, then the expiry pack will contain only C2, not C1.

`git repack` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/91badeba32d31d4dcc695a8888e5b697b4c3d90c/Documentation/git-repack.txt#L77-L82):

> ### `--expire-to=<dir>`
>
> Write a cruft pack containing pruned objects (if any) to the
> directory `<dir>`. This option is useful for keeping a copy of
> any pruned objects in a separate directory as a backup. Only
> useful with `--cruft -d`.

Example:

```bash
git repack -d \
            --cruft --cruft-expiration=5.minutes.ago \
            --expire-to="myRepo/objects/pack/pack
```

---

Note: with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), the use of `--max-pack-size` to allow multiple packfiles to be created is now supported even when we are sending unreachable objects to cruft packs.
Since `git gc` deals with unreachable objects, that can help.

See [commit c0b5d46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0b5d46ded46bf6e2cf4bb5325e4bf43374dd1ed), [commit 3843ef8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3843ef89312593a1e4d70bcdb29fd6ffa87134d6), [commit 61568ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61568efa95608fdafffe67967a82e88bcd90fade), [commit e741c07](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e741c078721f8232da769a1100433d96c4393b32) (28 Aug 2023) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8af5aac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8af5aac98667dfcce8ebe6efdb8df8aa0d134fb1), 07 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/pack-objects.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/61568efa95608fdafffe67967a82e88bcd90fade): support `--max-pack-size` with `--cruft`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> When pack-objects learned the `--cruft` option back in [b757353](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b757353676d6ffe1ac275366fa8b5b42b5d9727d) ("[`builtin/pack-objects.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b757353676d6ffe1ac275366fa8b5b42b5d9727d/builtin/pack-objects.c): `--cruft` without expiration", 2022-05-20, Git v2.37.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a50036da1a39806a8ae1aba2e2f2fea6f7fb8e08) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab336e8f1c8009c8b1aab8deb592148e69217085)), we explicitly forbade `--cruft` with `--max-pack-size`.
>
> At the time, there was no specific rationale given in the patch for not supporting the `--max-pack-size` option with `--cruft`.
> (As best I can remember, it's because we were trying to push users towards only ever having a single cruft pack, but I cannot be sure).
>
> However, `--max-pack-size` is flexible enough that it already works with `--cruft` and can shard unreachable objects across multiple cruft packs, creating separate ".mtimes" files as appropriate.
> In fact, the `--max-pack-size` option worked with `--cruft` as far back as [b757353](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b757353676d6ffe1ac275366fa8b5b42b5d9727d)!
>
> This is because we overwrite the `written_list`, and pass down the appropriate length, i.e.
> the number of objects written in each pack shard.

`git pack-objects` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/61568efa95608fdafffe67967a82e88bcd90fade/Documentation/git-pack-objects.txt#L119):

> options which imply `--revs`.

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), "[`git repack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/79861babe2d58387cd50010c9c63e4ef95afeb12/Documentation/git-repack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack))</sup> learned `--max-cruft-size` to prevent cruft packs from growing without bounds.

Since [`git gc` does run `git repack --cruft`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72527285/6309), that will help `git gc` to avoid leaving big crufts.

See [commit c1b754d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1b754d0597be83439ecc8de2a59a90f35cd4040) (07 Oct 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 3c1e2c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c1e2c2113842b8462803ef8c9aca596eacfd3af) (03 Oct 2023), and [commit 37dc6d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37dc6d81042ac41437163264e7a29d3bf50c8d90), [commit b5b1f4c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5b1f4c0ecf20c069d0301732edfdbfec167aa0c), [commit 78de1c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78de1c6c327b00ec9ed97c478e5f9e56d03c1db8) (02 Oct 2023) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 79861ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79861babe2d58387cd50010c9c63e4ef95afeb12), 18 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/repack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37dc6d81042ac41437163264e7a29d3bf50c8d90): implement support for `--max-cruft-size`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> Cruft packs are an alternative mechanism for storing a collection of unreachable objects whose mtimes are recent enough to avoid being pruned out of the repository.
>
> When cruft packs were first introduced back in [b757353](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b757353676d6ffe1ac275366fa8b5b42b5d9727d) ("[`builtin/pack-objects.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b757353676d6ffe1ac275366fa8b5b42b5d9727d/builtin/pack-objects.c): `--cruft` without expiration", 2022-05-20, Git v2.37.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a50036da1a39806a8ae1aba2e2f2fea6f7fb8e08) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab336e8f1c8009c8b1aab8deb592148e69217085)) and [a7d4938](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7d493833fe615211fd329183e59cec08496fb90) ("[`builtin/pack-objects.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a7d493833fe615211fd329183e59cec08496fb90/builtin/pack-objects.c): `--cruft` with expiration", 2022-05-20, Git v2.37.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a50036da1a39806a8ae1aba2e2f2fea6f7fb8e08) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab336e8f1c8009c8b1aab8deb592148e69217085)), the recommended workflow consisted of:
>
> - Repacking periodically, either by packing anything loose in the repository (via [`git repack -d`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/37dc6d81042ac41437163264e7a29d3bf50c8d90/Documentation/git-repack.txt#L60)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack#Documentation/git-repack.txt--d))</sup>) or producing a geometric sequence of packs (via [`git repack --geometric=<d> -d`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/37dc6d81042ac41437163264e7a29d3bf50c8d90/Documentation/git-repack.txt#L201)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack#Documentation/git-repack.txt---geometricltfactorgt))</sup>).
> - Every so often, splitting the repository into two packs, one cruft to store the unreachable objects, and another non-cruft pack to store the reachable objects.

See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72527285/6309) for details on crufts.

> Repositories may (out of band with the above) choose periodically to prune out some unreachable objects which have aged out of the grace period by generating a pack with `--cruft-expiration=<approxidate>`.
>
> This allowed repositories to maintain relatively few packs on average, and quarantine unreachable objects together in a cruft pack, avoiding the pitfalls of holding unreachable objects as loose while they age out (for more, see some of the details in [3d89a8c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d89a8c11801af1f7aae9d009240fd43cf322845) ("`Documentation/technical`: add cruft-packs.txt", 2022-05-20, Git v2.37.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a50036da1a39806a8ae1aba2e2f2fea6f7fb8e08) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab336e8f1c8009c8b1aab8deb592148e69217085))).
>
> This all works, but can be costly from an I/O-perspective when frequently repacking a repository that has many unreachable objects.
> This problem is exacerbated when those unreachable objects are rarely (if every) pruned.
>
> Since there is at most one cruft pack in the above scheme, each time we update the cruft pack it must be rewritten from scratch.
> Because much of the pack is reused, this is a relatively inexpensive operation from a CPU-perspective, but is very costly in terms of I/O since we end up rewriting basically the same pack (plus any new unreachable objects that have entered the repository since the last time a cruft pack was generated).
>
> At the time, we decided against implementing more robust support for multiple cruft packs.
> This patch implements that support which we were lacking.
>
> Introduce a new option `--max-cruft-size` which allows repositories to accumulate cruft packs up to a given size, after which point a new generation of cruft packs can accumulate until it reaches the maximum size, and so on.
> To generate a new cruft pack, the process works like so:
>
> - Sort a list of any existing cruft packs in ascending order of pack size.
> - Starting from the beginning of the list, group cruft packs together while the accumulated size is smaller than the maximum specified pack size.
> - Combine the objects in these cruft packs together into a new cruft pack, along with any other unreachable objects which have since entered the repository.
>
> Once a cruft pack grows beyond the size specified via `--max-cruft-size` the pack is effectively frozen.
> This limits the I/O churn up to a quadratic function of the value specified by the `--max-cruft-size` option, instead of behaving quadratically in the number of total unreachable objects.
>
> When pruning unreachable objects, we bypass the new code paths which combine small cruft packs together, and instead start from scratch, passing in the appropriate `--max-pack-size` down to `pack-objects`, putting it in charge of keeping the resulting set of cruft packs sized correctly.
>
> This may seem like further I/O churn, but in practice it isn't so bad.
> We could prune old cruft packs for whom all or most objects are removed, and then generate a new cruft pack with just the remaining set of objects.
> But this additional complexity buys us relatively little, because most objects end up being pruned anyway, so the I/O churn is well contained.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/37dc6d81042ac41437163264e7a29d3bf50c8d90/Documentation/config/gc.txt#L89-L94):

> ### `gc.maxCruftSize`
>
> Limit the size of new cruft packs when repacking. When
> specified in addition to `--max-cruft-size`, the command line
> option takes priority. See the `--max-cruft-size` option of
> [`git repack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack).

`git gc` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/37dc6d81042ac41437163264e7a29d3bf50c8d90/Documentation/git-gc.txt#L62-L68):

> ### `--max-cruft-size=<n>`
>
> When packing unreachable objects into a cruft pack, limit the
> size of new cruft packs to be at most `<n>` bytes. Overrides any
> value specified via the `gc.maxCruftSize` configuration. See
> the `--max-cruft-size` option of [`git repack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack) for
> more.

`git repack` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/37dc6d81042ac41437163264e7a29d3bf50c8d90/Documentation/git-repack.txt#L77-L87):

> ### `--max-cruft-size=<n>`
>
> Repack cruft objects into packs as large as `<n>` bytes before
> creating new packs. As long as there are enough cruft packs
> smaller than `<n>`, repacking will cause a new cruft pack to
> be created containing objects from any combined cruft packs,
> along with any new unreachable objects. Cruft packs larger than
> `<n>` will not be modified. When the new cruft pack is larger
> than `<n>` bytes, it will be split into multiple packs, all of
> which are guaranteed to be at most `<n>` bytes in size. Only
> useful with `--cruft -d`.